# Can I read data from realtime data base across cloud functions in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to read and write data in database real time across cloud functions but I don't know if this is possible, also I don't know if this is good practice or if is better make this through with SDK database realtime

I learning firebase and react native, I am new learning these topics.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.
>
> Cloud Functions runs Node v.6.11.5, so we recommend that you develop locally with this version.

You are able to use realtime database trigggers like `onCreate()`, `onWrite()`. Also you are able to use `set()` to send data to the realtime database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: I'm writing some function in client side and i want to move them to cloud function, but  how to handle the results in my own UI?